# Sorting by average, then inserting into new table using Hive

Tags: sql, mapreduce, hive

I have a large datafile that looks like this:

```
    1   6
    1   6
    2   7
    3   2
    3   6
    1   7
    1   9
    2   9
    1   5
    3   9
    3   1
    2   8
```

I want to group the data by the first column, find the 2nd column average for each first column value, then sort those groupings by the 2nd column average.  So the output should be:

```
    2   8
    1   6.6
    3   4.5
```

My code looks like this right now, and does not work:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE as (a STRING, b INT)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LOCATION 's3n://myfolder/hive';

    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE output(a STRING, avgb DOUBLE)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LOCATION 's3n://myfolder/hive';

    load data inpath "s3n://myfolder/file.txt" into TABLE as;
    insert overwrite output select a, avg(b) from as group by a order by avg(b) DESC limit 1000;
```

I should note that the following DOES work, but something isn't working with the order by and insert steps that work for me in SQL:

```
    select a, avg(b) from as group by a;
```

When I try:

```
    select a, avg(b) from as group by a order by avg(b);
```

I get "FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:66 Invalid table alias or column reference 'b': (possible column names are: _col0, _col1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just shift it out in a subquery:

```
select a
from (select a, avg(b) as avgb from as group by a) as t
order by avgb;
```

Comment: specific reasons to put in subquery?? Could you please explain it also

Comment: @vikrantrana: see the question.